# Библиотека для поворота карточек свайпом

Tags: java, android, mobile-development, library, android-library

Прошу помочь в поиске библиотеки, которая позволит выполнять следующее:

- поворачивать карточку на "другую" сторону
- поворачивать с помощью свайпа
- возможность определять в какую сторону была повёрнута карта и в зависимости от этого отображать информацию на второй половине

Надеюсь получилось объяснить более-менее доходчиво)